# Connecting from AWS Beanstalk to on-premise database and .NET services

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a **ASP.NET Core MVC 5** app that I want to deploy in **AWS Beanstalk** and communicate with **some .NET services and SQL database** in the on-premise. How can I achieve that? Can I achieve it by creating a VPN connection?

Comment: Yes, VPN is one way.

Comment: Can you point to any documentation in AWS or example? I was not able to locate.

Comment: AWS provides [managed service](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/) for VPN.

Comment: If you can put your comment as an answer, I can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

One way to enable **private** connectivity between application running on Elastic Beanstalk (EB) and on-premise database is through VPN. AWS provides managed service for that called [AWS Site-to-Site VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/VPC_VPN.html).

The other solution, though much more expensive, is through [AWS Direct Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html) (DX). Unlike VPN, DX connectivity does not involve internet which generally improves security, bandwidth and latency of the connection.